# Use Jquery load method unlimited times for a like button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am programming something like a tinder picture which you vote on ( but not for dating but the same concept). I want this Voting window, or rather said div, to refresh after you clicked the for example like button. But not the whole page because of the cashed images in the browser and the ugly static look when you post data via php post method and have to refresh the whole page. I did structure it like this now:

```
$('#indexMiddleLayout').load('rateableWindow.php');
```

The above line comes before in the script tag so the content gets loaded to begin with and the next code line comes after to make it possible to reload again when a sertain button is clicked.

```
$('#iML-VotingButtonRight').click(function () {
    $('#indexMiddleLayout').load('rateableWindow.php');
});
```

This refreshes my div now but only once :/

I was putting the whole div and it's containing stuff into a seperate php file which i, after you clicked the like button, want to refresh with a ajax request which adds data to the sql database telling it has been liked and after that success i'd like the div or rather the included page to reload so only that div refreshes.

Comment: This does load the data every time you click, the problem is most likely that the data the serverside returns never changes.

Comment: Is id `iML-VotingButtonRight` available in **rateableWindow.php** page?

Comment: More than likely, your button is inside a form and clicking it is calling the default behaviour of submitting that form. Change your handler to `$('#iML-VotingButtonRight').click(function (event) {  
event.preventDefault(); `

Comment: @NanaPartykar yes

Comment: Change `$('#iML-VotingButtonRight').click(function () {` to `$(document).on('click', "#iML-VotingButtonRight", function(e) {` and check.

Comment: @NanaPartykar yeah, I thought the OP was saying that the problem was the form was submitting, but it seems maybe it is just the issue with dynamic binding

Comment: @DelightedD0D: Yes, it seems so. I'm also waiting for the reply. Let us see, what OP Replies.

Comment: alright i got to work a bit with the php errors but the div now refreshes unlimited times :) thanks! :D @NanaPartykar & DelightedD0D!